# GetAxis not working (not sensing my input?)

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image: pic of the unity set up]

My set up in the image you can see the blend tree which works if I pull the sliders but does not register when i press play wasd or updownleftright do not work on the keyboard, however other animations do work i'm following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wdOk5QXYC6Y&t=1376s

Here's my script:

```
 public class player2 : MonoBehaviour 
 {    
     public Animator anim;
     private float inputH,inputV;

     private void Start() 
     {
         anim = GetComponent<Animator>();            
     }
     private void Update() 
     {
         if (Input.GetKeyDown("1")) anim.Play("WAIT01", -1, 0f);
         if (Input.GetKeyDown("2")) anim.Play("WAIT02", -1, 0f);
         if (Input.GetKeyDown("3")) anim.Play("WAIT03", -1, 0f);
         if (Input.GetKeyDown("4")) anim.Play("WAIT04", -1, 0f);

         if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
         {
             int n = Random.Range(0,2);

             if (n == 0)
                  anim.Play("DAMAGED00", -1,0f);
             else anim.Play("DAMAGED01", -1,0f);
         }    

         inputH = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
         inputV = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

         anim.SetFloat("inputH", inputH);
         anim.SetFloat("inputv", inputV);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Maybe you have change the input default settings, see the first picture on [Unity manual Input Manager](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-InputManager.html).

Comment: Yes I assumed it would be something like this. Thanks kindly